# Understanding jsperf.com benchmark

Tags: jquery, arrays

I'm trying to make sense of this benchmarking:

http://jsperf.com/for-vs-jq-inarray

This test suggests that on iPad, the jQuery option runs faster. I ran it on my iPad, and the results proved this. But why?!

Here is jQuery inArray:

```
inArray: function( elem, arr, i ) { var len;

    if ( arr ) {
        if ( core_indexOf ) {
            return core_indexOf.call( arr, elem, i );
        }

        len = arr.length;
        i = i ? i < 0 ? Math.max( 0, len + i ) : i : 0;

        for ( ; i < len; i++ ) {
            // Skip accessing in sparse arrays
            if ( i in arr && arr[ i ] === elem ) {
                return i;
            }
        }
    }

    return -1;
}
```

It is essentially the same as the native javascript samples except this time with added jQuery bloat. How is it possible that the iPad runs this faster?

I minified and optimized the 2 native samples and re-ran the test, but with negligible change.

Why is jQuery faster than native javascript on the iPad in this instance?

Comment: If you look at the absolute values of the performance numbers, maybe you should be asking why the iPad runs the `for` loops so slowly.

Comment: If that was the case, then the jQuery would be just as bad. It runs practically the same for loop.

Comment: Does the iPad implement an inArray method on the Array object? If it does, jQuery would use it instead, and it may be more optimized than the jquery equivalent.

Comment: No, it doesn't run the same `for` loop.  If there's a native `indexOf()` function (which there is), it uses that and doesn't use it's own `for` loop implementation.